# a stronger fixed point theorem

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

Given a unary predicate $\phi$, the Fixed Point Lemma of PA tells us that there is a sentence $S$ such that:

$$\mbox{PA} \vdash S \leftrightarrow \phi (\ulcorner S \urcorner)$$

(Note that $\phi$ doesn't even have to be in the language of arithmetic - $\phi$ could, for example, be some sort of truth predicate T, as to prove the Fixed Point Lemma there is no requirement that induction hold of predicates involving $\phi$.)

My question is whether one can say something stronger: namely, there is a sentence $S$ such that $S$ and $\phi(\ulcorner S \urcorner)$ are literally (i.e., syntactically) the same sentence.

I have heard people talk as if this also holds, but I don't see how the usual proof of the Fixed Point Lemma gives this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was [discussed at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83155/can-we-find-strong-fixed-points-in-the-fixed-point-lemma-of-g%C3%B6dels-incompletene) *(and so I've made this answer CW)*. Briefly, **some but not all** Godel numberings admit such "strong fixed points."

It's easy to verify that none of the usual Godel numberings admit strong fixed points: just check that in any of the usual numbering the Godel number of the numeral of $k$ is greater than $k$ for every natural number $k$. So numbering systems which do admit strong fixed points have to be a bit complicated. The existence of such a numbering was originally claimed by Kripke without proof; a proof appears in Visser's $2002$ paper *Semantics and the Liar Paradox*.